# colour row to match a specific cell colour

Tags: excel, vba

i have a spreadsheet where the values are pasted from elsewhere and have different colour formatting each time. What i would like to do is set the row colour to match the colour of a specific cell. i have used the following code to set the interior colour (see below).

Currently i need to repeat this line of code for every row in my sheet, how can i make the code shorter and not have to reference every row?

```
    Private Sub Work:sheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Me.Range("G114:AH114").Interior.Color = Me.Range("B114").Interior.Color
Me.Range("G115:AH115").Interior.Color = Me.Range("B115").Interior.Color
Me.Range("G116:AH116").Interior.Color = Me.Range("B116").Interior.Color
Me.Range("G117:AH117").Interior.Color = Me.Range("B117").Interior.Color
Me.Range("G118:AH118").Interior.Color = Me.Range("B118").Interior.Color
Me.Range("G119:AH119").Interior.Color = Me.Range("B119").Interior.Color
Me.Range("G120:AH120").Interior.Color = Me.Range("B120").Interior.Color
    End Sub
```

thanks

Comment: Check out for loop, I’m sure someone will answer this shortly with exactly that.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about that but i need a little head start :)

Comment: you got your answer too. I would’ve answered but was in a cab.

Answer (score 2):

You could modify sheet name and row variable and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Row As Long

    Row = 114

    Do Until Row = 121

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

            .Cells(Row, 2).Interior.Color = .Cells(Row, 7).Interior.Color

        End With

        Row = Row + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi mate, This is close to what i want. ill post my modifications one finished. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help; I have used the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Row As Long

    Row = 88

    Do Until Row = 121

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Two Weekly Plan 2019")

            .Range(Cells(Row, 7), Cells(Row, 34)).Interior.Color = .Cells(Row, 2).Interior.Color

        End With

        Row = Row + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```